# Can I pass an identifier to a macro but have the macro "see" the data it represents?

Tags: rust, metaprogramming, rust-macros

*Specs:*

- *Rust nightly build 1.53.0*
- *unstringify! crate dependency https://docs.rs/unstringify/0.1.1/unstringify/macro.unstringify.html*

I am building a simple macro to call an attribute on a struct when the attribute's name is passed in as a string, like so:

`send!(struct, "title"); // => struct.title`  **Works**

So far the above code works, because "title" is entered in as a verbatim string literal.  But to be useful I want to pass in a `my_str` identifier for a string literal and have it be treated like the string literal I passed in above (basically like how things work in a normal function).

`let my_str = "title";`

`send!(struct, my_str); // => struct.title`  **Doesn't Work**

The code above gives me this error:

> expected a string literal, a verbatim `stringify!` call, or a verbatim `concat!` call.

Here is the code for the send! macro I created.

```
macro_rules! send {
    ($obj:ident, $msg:expr) => {
        unstringify!(
            let $x = unstringify!($msg) in {
                $obj . $x
            } 
        )
    }
}
```

If the above code looks confusing let me explain.  It is saying call unstringify! on `$msg` and assign to `$x` then output `$obj . $x` as the final result.  It is NOT two unstringify! calls *(refer to the [unstringify! reference](https://docs.rs/unstringify/0.1.1/unstringify/macro.unstringify.html) material for any questions on that)*

I know other macros like Rust's `println!` macro can handle either literals passed in or variables and treats them as the same.  How can I achieve this in the send! macro?

Comment: This isn't possible.  What you need instead is to `match` on the value of the string.

Comment: `my_str` doesn't *represent* anything inside a macro: it's not a variable, it's just the identifier `my_str`. If you want the value of a variable that's set at runtime, you can't get it at compile time.

Comment: You seem to want reflection. This isn't really related to macros.

Comment: What could be possible with macros is to change the struct itself to have an additional function doing the mapping. But this would be a macro on the struct type definition, not on the call.

Comment: @trentcl  If that is true, how can `println!()` handle variables like this `println!("My value {}", my_str)` and yield a result?

Comment: `println!("{}", my_str)` expands to more code that contains the identifier `my_str`. It doesn't evaluate `my_str` at compile time, otherwise it wouldn't work at all with strings that come from user input.

Comment: @RandallCoding: See the expansion of that `println!` macro invocation [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3fd6a8bfcfb9bdabd7001b98d3312901).

Comment: @trentcl & eggyal  Thanks, that makes sense.